# How to return query results as JSON string -- FOR JSON AUTO throws syntax error

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a SQL Query that is supposed to return results as a JSON string, however using FOR JSON AUTO gives me a syntax error I can't seem to work around.

I am using SSMS 2017, I am aware that the FOR JSON AUTO statement doesn't work for versions before 2016.

Here is my Query:

```
    SELECT Username, UserID
    FROM [dbo].[Users]
    WHERE Username like 'John'
    FOR JSON AUTO;
```

The error occurs at the word 'JSON' and gives the error "Incorrect Syntax near 'JSON' "

Once resolved, the query output will display the results in a JSON string.

Has anyone encountered this error and can reproduce it? Any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL do you use? You can check as follows `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: Just realized the problem. I am talking to a remote DB that is using SSMS 2014, I thought it was running the same version as my local DB, which is running 2017. Thanks for the help!